# Object-Oriented Programming in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, simulation

I would consider myself an intermediate beginner in Python as I have completed all but the last few chapters of LPTHW and have completed several other tutorials as well. However, I cannot seem to figure out OOP. Let me give an example. If I tried to write a simple city sim game, could I have a class 'Buildings', with a method called 'function' that changes what it does depending on the parameters? So, take for example this

```
class Buildings(object):
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function
    def function(self):
        if function == '1':
            print 'blablabla'
        elif function == '2':
            print 'blablabla'



Granary = Building('1')
Granary.function()
```

(replacing numbers with actual names of actions and print statements with actual functions)
Is this how classes are supposed to be used? (after all, 'There should be preferably one and only one way of doing things' is apparently what pythonistas are supossed to believe :p)
Or is there a more efficient way of doing this? Or am I an idiot?

Comment: Thats a definite yes, but only if `self.function` changes. In the example that you are showing us, it will not change because you are clearly defining `self.function` statically to a value of `'1'`, which will result in `'blablabla'`.

Comment: There's a number of errors in your code.  `Building` vs `Buildings`, the `function`s in the `if/elif` statements should be `self.function`...

Comment: I wrote this in a rush, but hopefully you can get the meaning.

Comment: I think you should make `Building` a `super class` and `Granary`, `Library` and so on its `subclasses`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I think you want:

```
class Buildings(object):
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function
    # Don't name an attribute the same as a method
    def myMethod(self):
        # Use self.function instead of function
        if self.function == '1':
            print 'blablabla'
        elif self.function == '2':
            print 'blablabla'



Granary = Buildings('1')
Granary.myMethod()
```

**Edit:**

Going by what you said in your comments, I have to say the answer depends on what you plan to do.  Every scenario is different and in one, something might not be the best solution even though it *was* the best in another.  Usually, there isn't really a reason to make a whole class with only one method.  For example, in your above code, you can also do:

```
def Buildings(function):
    if function == '1':
        print 'blablabla'
    elif function == '2':
        print 'blablabla'
Buildings('1')
```

to get the exact same result.

Comment: @Downvoter - Could you please list a reason you downvoted?  I take the quality of my work very seriously.  So, if you found a problem, please let me know so that I can either fix my post or explain better what I did.

Comment: Might have been a misclick when he meant to approve instead.

Comment: @Core2uu - No, the answer was already accepted.  Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the class rewritten to do what I think you want it to:

```
class Building(object):
    def __init__(self, case):
        self.case = case
    def function(self):
        if self.case == '1':
            print 'blablabla'
        elif self.case == '2':
            print 'blablabla'



Granary = Building('1')
Granary.function()
```

There are numerous ways to do what you want and above is one.

Comment: so basically, I can do it this way? Is it the most efficient way? I heard once on this site that making a class with only __init__ and one method is a complicated way of doing something which should be easy.

Comment: This will explode because `Building` isn't defined.  Do `Granary = Buildings('1')`

Comment: lol I think one run of the program would have told me that. I am a newbie and I wrote this code in about 20 seconds. You got the meaning so it's all good right?